# ExportAttribute() is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am converting our source code to use Xamarin.iOS unified api (rather painfully... Xamarin). Currently I have a bunch of errors of this flavor:

ExportAttribute() is inaccessible due to its protection level

I understand there is no longer a public parameter-less constructor - so what am I supposed to provide the ExportAttribute constructor to get this to work - I am not the original author of this code so I am not exactly sure what to do here. I have a method like this:

```
  [Foundation.Export()]
  private void CameraSnapshotComplete()
  {
  }
```

What do I pass to the ExportAttribute constructor in tihs case? This method is being sent to the AnimationDidStop method like this:

```
  UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("CameraSnapshotComplete"));
```

So do I just pass "CameraSnapshotComplete" to the constructor? I have a zillion of these to replace - so would like a little feedback before I start doing this and find out I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the selector is named `CameraSnapshotComplete` then the `[Export]` attribute must use the same name. IOW if you call it like this:

```
UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("CameraSnapshotComplete"));
```

then the method should be exported like:

```
[Foundation.Export("CameraSnapshotComplete")]
private void CameraSnapshotComplete()
{
}
```

In many cases there are API alternative, to using selectors, that will make the code more strongly typed (and avoid potential typos that are hard to debug).

Comment: Understand that there are 'better' ways to do some of this. But a lot of this code is back from the MonoTouch days and re-writing it is not an option for us right now. Currently have half a million lines to go through for this port to the new unified api.

Comment: I understand :-) but, as a general rule, I want my answers to be applicable to everyone who will read it (today or in 2 years).

Comment: FWIW, I've written some migration code for the upcoming Xamarin Studio 5.7 to auto-migrate a lot of the stuff, although it does not cover everything.