# Xamarin Forms: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, xamarin.forms, uitabbar

I have a custom navigation renderer that should hide bars on swipe:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CNavigationPage), typeof(CNavigationRenderer))]
namespace TabbedPageDemo.iOS
{
    class CNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                this.HidesBarsOnSwipe = true;
                this.BarHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer.AddTarget(this, new Selector("swipeGesture:"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In PCL, MainPage is set to a tabbed page. Each tab is an instance of CNavigationPage. When I run the project, I'm getting:

```
Objective-C e
xception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[TabbedPageDemo_iOS_CNavigationRenderer swipeGesture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Anybody knows why `swipeGesture` is not recognized?

Comment: Do you have a registered "swipeGesture:" method?

Comment: I dont think so? Can you tell me how to register it?

Comment: Look at this answer to see how to register your method via using the `Export` attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27254298/4984832

Answer (score 0):

You shall see below in your IDE.
View -> Pad -> Toolbox, 
In Toolbox, properties->Events..
there should be another controller event on same control which you didn't make.